# How do i conditionally return function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I just try to create a React Native library, and currently I've a use case that my function can be declared using

- `const show = useMyHook()`

or

- `const {show, hide} = useMyHook()`

`useMyHook.js`

```
const useMyHook = () => {
  const MyCTX = useContext(MyContext);
  if (!MyCTX) {
    throw new Error('useMyHook must be defined.');
  }
  // how do i conditionally return
  // return {show: MyCTX.show, hide:MyCTX.hide}
  // and
  // return MyCTX.show
  return MyCTX.show;
};

export default useMyHook;
```

what should i do to make `useMyHook()` accept both of them? or is it not possible?

the main reason why I want `useMyHook()` can accept both of them is, so dev can naming anything into variable when they only want to call `show()` as a function like so:

`const showMyHookInBannerHomepage = useMyHook()`

i think it's more simple rather than

`const {show:showMyHookInBannerHomepage} = useMyHook()`

Comment: i wouldn't do that - just return both and let the destructuring to make the decision

Comment: The function only knows what is given to it.  You would have to use a parameter to convey your wishes.  Having said that, just return both as Daniel says.

Comment: Putting aside whether or not you *should* do this (I don't see any reason to), what stops you?  You can *conditionally* perform one operation or another by using an `if` statement.  What condition are you looking to use?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: it's just because in my `show` function, I've call `hide` using timeout, but sometime i need to call `hide` manually in case my `show` function returning 0 duration (ignore `hide()`)

Comment: @David i just can't thinking what's the right condition to returning as my `code commenting`, `if (function declared as destructuring) return {show: MyCTX.show, hide:MyCTX.hide}`

Comment: @flix: There's no such thing as "function declared as destructuring".  What the consuming code does with the value returned by a function, if anything, is not the function's concern.  The function performs its logic and returns its result.  What result it returns is up to the function.  If in this case there's no logical condition by which the function can determine one return value over another, that sounds like a reason not to change what it returns.  Overall it sounds like this is a non-issue.

Comment: @David i'm feeling silly and dilemma right now, xD, i think i will take what Daniel A. White suggested, thank you everyone

Comment: One way is to do something like if you like allowing some argument to `useMyHook()`: https://notepad.pw/q8kljHv2FTup2h7oBhQK

Comment: @mandy8055 thank you for the suggestion, I've changed my mind to refactor my function to be able use `useMyHook()` and `useMyHook.hide()`

Comment: @mandy8055 i think StackOverflow wouldn't allow us to off-topic about my post above xD

Comment: @flix it's not off-topic. Take a look at this approach. I tried putting comments. Please let me know if that work: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wonderful-flower-kv7d8f?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A47%2C11. Try commenting one and uncommenting the other to check both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way which I can think of is to make the hook work for both use cases by returning a function with properties attached to it. Something like:

```js
function useMyHook() {
  const MyCTX = useContext(MyContext);
  if (!MyCTX) {
    throw new Error("useMyHook must be defined.");
  }

  // Create a function that calls MyCTX.show
  const callableFunction = function() {
    return MyCTX.show();
  };

  // Attach show and hide properties to the function
  callableFunction.show = MyCTX.show;
  callableFunction.hide = MyCTX.hide;

  return callableFunction;
}

// Usage 
// Either
const { show, hide } = useMyHook();
// Or
const show = useMyHook();
```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wonderful-flower-kv7d8f?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A7%2C1-23%2C2)***

---

##### Alternative Approach

Another way would require you to use a parameter(if you like to change the signature of your hook) to your hook based on which you can conditionally use them. A sample would look like:

```js
const useMyHook = (returnObject = false) => {
  const MyCTX = useContext(MyContext);
  if (!MyCTX) {
    throw new Error('useMyHook must be defined.');
  }
  // Conditionally return based on the `returnObject` parameter
  if (returnObject) {
    return {show: MyCTX.show, hide: MyCTX.hide};
  } else {
    return MyCTX.show;
  }
};

// To use

// Just get the `show` function
const show = useMyHook();

// Get both `show` and `hide` functions in an object
const {show, hide} = useMyHook(true);
```

**SIDENOTE:**

1. You can also leverage ***[Proxy API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)*** to achieve your requirement. Although, there might be some performance bottleneck to it(in case you're ready to sacrifice some) since it intercepts and redefines operations on objects.
2. If there is not a very specific need I would stick to the destructure approach and leave it on devs(using the hook) as what they want to destructure from the hook.

Answer (score 1):

Note that destructuring assignment will happily ignore any properties that aren't mentioned; so even without doing anything special, any callers that don't need `hide` can simply write:

```
const {show} = useMyHook();
```

That's what I'd recommend unless you have a particularly strong reason to do something different. I say this not because the above is trivial to implement (though it is), but because it's trivial to understand. Any other approach makes it hard to describe what `useMyHook` returns.

Comment: i just think using destructuring _force_ someone use my function to declare `show` as variable even though they can `aliasing` it, but what i want to approach is, they can declare whatever they want something like `const ShowMyHookInHomepage = useMyHook()` rather than `const {show:ShowMyHookInHomepage} = useMyHook()`

Comment: @flix: How about `const ShowMyHookInHomepage = useMyHook().show`?

Comment: I never thought i able to use `useMyHook()` like that xD, i always thinking of hook always stop at `useMyHook()`